# Pushbots notification app crash

Tags: android, apache-cordova

> Hello, i use, cordova + pushbots + framework7 project, when i send a push notification for android 4.2.2, if application still background my app crash... in version above 5.0, this works fine....

01-22 21:50:30.206 15557-16843/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer I/PB3: Received a Notification.

01-22 21:50:30.206 15557-16843/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer I/PB3: customHandler:com.pushbots.plugin.PushHandler

01-22 21:50:30.206 15557-16843/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer E/data: Bundle[{google.sent_time=1485129029326, message=tste123, collapse_key=do_not_collapse, pb_n_id=588545454520d4750da470c7, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, from=237724424113, google.message_id=0:1485129029337800%63cdadd5f9fd7ecd}]

01-22 21:50:30.216 15557-15557/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer D/PB3: action=com.pushbots.MSG_RECEIVE

01-22 21:50:30.227 15557-15557/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer D/PB3: Sending success result: {"data":{"message":"tste123","google.sent_time":1485129029326,"pb_n_id":"588545454520d4750da470c7","android.support.content.wakelockid":1,"from":"237724424113","collapse_key":"do_not_collapse","google.message_id":"0:1485129029337800%63cdadd5f9fd7ecd"},"type":"received"}

01-22 21:50:30.237 15557-16843/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer D/PB3: TEST1: iconNameic_pushbots_licon

01-22 21:50:30.267 15557-15557/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

01-22 21:50:30.267 15557-15557/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41fd4960)
01-22 21:50:30.297 15557-15557/org.devgirl.framework7.mediaexplorer

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver com.pushbots.plugin.PushHandler: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2462)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                          at android.webkit.WebViewClassic.setNetworkAvailable(WebViewClassic.java:4208)
                                                                                          at android.webkit.WebView.setNetworkAvailable(WebView.java:731)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine$1.setNetworkAvailable(SystemWebViewEngine.java:113)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue$OnlineEventsBridgeMode$2.run(NativeToJsMessageQueue.java:338)
                                                                                          at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:4843)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.engine.SystemWebViewEngine$1.runOnUiThread(SystemWebViewEngine.java:117)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue$OnlineEventsBridgeMode.onNativeToJsMessageAvailable(NativeToJsMessageQueue.java:334)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue.enqueueMessage(NativeToJsMessageQueue.java:249)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.NativeToJsMessageQueue.addPluginResult(NativeToJsMessageQueue.java:238)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewImpl.sendPluginResult(CordovaWebViewImpl.java:307)
                                                                                          at org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext.sendPluginResult(CallbackContext.java:61)
                                                                                          at com.pushbots.plugin.PushbotsPlugin.sendSuccessData(PushbotsPlugin.java:190)
                                                                                          at com.pushbots.plugin.PushHandler.onReceive(PushHandler.java:84)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2455)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:157) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1365) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5317) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869) 
                                                                                          at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)